# How to get day of week using PHP?

Tags: php, date

This is my code

```
<select name="weekly_set">
<?php
for($days=1;$days<=7;$days++)
{
$selected='';   
if(date("N")==$days)
$selected ='selected';
echo "<option value=".$days." $selected>".$days."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

In drop down I want to show day of the week like Monday, Tuesday... How to show? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<select name="weekly_set">
<?php
    $daysArray = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
    for($days=1;$days<=7;$days++) {
        $selected='';   
        if(date("N")==$days)
            $selected ='selected';
        echo "<option value=".$days." $selected>". $daysArray[$days-1]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have the formating info for the date function [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php)., so `date('l')` is the easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will print select box as you want.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
$dayArray = array();
echo '<select name="weekly_set">';
for ($days = 0; $days < 7; $days++) {
$selected='';   
if(date("N")==$days)
$selected ='selected';
    echo "<option value=".$days." $selected>".strftime('%A', $timestamp)."</option>";
 $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
echo '</select>';
```